# ConnectionString configSource not found when deployed to Azure

Tags: azure, web-config, connection-string

I am securing my MVC5 project, by moving the connection strings out of web.config into an external file, and not checking this into source control, nor adding it to the project.

My web.config looks like

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings configSource="ConnectionStrings.config" />
```

This works perfectly in development.

I have the website hosted in Azure WebSites, and I have manually defined the connectionstrings in the configuration portal.

The problem is that when I publish to Azure, I get the error 
**"Unable to open configSource file 'ConnectionStrings.config'."**

Is there a way to override the Connection Strings element in the web.config so it will not try and find the external file? Is Web Transforms able to do this?

Thanks in advance, all help appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a RemoveAttributes transform on the web.config and remove the configSource attribute on deploy to Azure.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I do:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="Entities" connectionString="" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I use EF, so it expects that; if you have name = "myConnection" then that is what will be reflected above; connectionString="" can remain blank;

Then in azure -> Config, under Connection String, for Name I have Entities for Value I have my EF connection string.

Azure will over-write your web.config as long as you match the Name; does that make sense?

After messing around with this... this may seem like a workaround... strip out the connection string value from ConnectionStrings.config, then check it in commit and push, then add it to your ignore list (gitignore) commit and push., that should stop the errors from showing up since the file now exists; it doesn't have your sensitive data., and now the config values should propagate to the config - Im sure uve thought of this already but this seems like the simplest workaround.

Comment: Inside the Azure configuration (i.e. in the Portal) I have 3 standard connection strings defined

Comment: I will usually checkin my dev connection string with no password. Then in Azure and I use EF so my config has this section - Updated my answer above.

Comment: Also; can you check to make sure that you have ConnectionStrings.config set to "Copy Always"... :) that should get your existing thing going if you want to stick with it

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but it's not quite going to work. Firstly, regarding the "Copy Always", remember that the connectionstrings file is NOT part of the solution/project, it is just a file that sits in the project directory. This keeps it out of Source Control.

Comment: Secondly, adding the empty connectionstring entities in web.config and then overriding them in Azure portal won't help us when we're in Local Debug mode. The idea is to have a clean file that devs store on the local machine that manages the connection strings, some of which are highly secure and non-trivial.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Joel. Now it all makes sense; let me try overwriting the setting for configSource.

Comment: Can you show us the text in your ConnectionStrings.config (with the password/private data redacted)

Comment: Okay - What if you checked in a ConnectionStrings.config that did not have any value in connectionString, i.e. connectionString=""?

Comment: this would allow your dev's to keep whatever they wanted in local debug mode as it would be ignored by gitignore (or whatever scm you use) - note, updated answer