# Setting up Azure portal to use connectionString as app setting without code

Tags: c#, azure, connection-string

I'm relatively new to Azure and Web development and I'm trying to figure out a way to use my connectionString from my Web App Service's Configuraton blade. My understanding is that I should be able to overwrite the connectionString using the portal's Connection Strings instead of the dummy value I have specified in my Web.Config. I would like to do this without any changes to source code.

I have already added the connection string in the portal as follows:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUdhx.jpg

I hoped that this would be enough to override the connectionString being provided in the source code.

My Web.Config file is as follows:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxxx" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->

    <section name="configBuilders" type="System.Configuration.ConfigurationBuildersSection, System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxxx" restartOnExternalChanges="false" requirePermission="false" />

  </configSections>

  <configBuilders>
    <builders>
      <add name="AzureKeyVault" vaultName="xxxxxxxxxxxx" type="Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.AzureKeyVaultConfigBuilder, Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.Azure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral" vaultUri="https://xxxxxxxxxxxx.vault.azure.net/" />
    </builders>
  </configBuilders>

  <!--<connectionStrings>
    <add name="SchoolContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=ContosoUniversity2;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>-->
  <!--Azure connection string-->
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SchoolContext" connectionString="thisdoesntmatter" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <!-- <add name="ContosoUniversityLogin" connectionString="metadata=res://*/LoginData.csdl|res://*/LoginData.ssdl|res://*/LoginData.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=XXX.database.windows.net;initial catalog=ContosoUniversity;persist security info=True;user id=XXX;password=XXX;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
   -->
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="connectionString" value="dummy" />
  </appSettings>
```

The connection string stored in the portal is as follows: (Removed the ID and password for security):

Server=tcp:XXX.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=ContosoUniversity;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=XXX;Password=XXX;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;

Comment: The connection string you created in the portal is named `connectionString`, is that what you intended? I don't see any connection strings in your configuration named that. I see an *appsetting* named `connectionString`, but appsettings are separate from connection strings.

Comment: Fixed! This post helped: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27715083/connectionstring-configsource-not-found-when-deployed-to-azure

Comment: The name was SchoolContext not connectionString. I thought the name of the connection string was connectionString in Web.Config under appSettings but it was actually SchoolContext

Comment: Please add this as an answer as it will help other who have the same ask.